# Python parsing an ugly configuration file

Tags: python, parsing

I have an application generating a weird config file

```
app_id1 {
key1 = val
key2 = val
...
}
app_id2 {
key1 = val
key2 = val
...
}
...
```

And I am struggling on how to parse this in python. The keys of each app may vary too.
I can't change the application to generate the configuration file in some easily parsable format :)

Any suggestions on how to do this pythonically ?
I am thinking along the lines of dict of dict

```
conf = {'app_id1': {'key1' : 'val', 'key2' : 'val'},
        'app_id2' : {'key1' : 'val', 'key2' : 'val'}
       }
```

Comment: That seems a lot a like a dict anyway, only with `\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: Yeah, Can you read this into your file, then replace '=' with ':' and voila, you have a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

I assumed you read the content of the file to a string

```
config_file_string = '''app_id1 {
key1 = val
key2 = val
key3 = val
}
app_id2 {
key1 = val
key2 = val
}'''

config = {}
appid = ''
for line in config_file_string.splitlines():
    print(line)
    if line.endswith('{'):
        appid = line.split()[0].strip()
        placeholder_dict = {}
    elif line.startswith('}'):
        config[appid] = placeholder_dict
    else:
        placeholder_dict[line.split('=')[0].strip()] = line.split('=')[1].strip()

print(config)
```

This returns:

```
{'app_id2': {'key2 ': ' val', 'key1 ': ' val'}, 'app_id1': {'key3 ': ' val', 'key2 ': ' val', 'key1 ': ' val'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex: `(\w+)\s*\{([^}]*)` will find a `name { values }` construct, and `([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*([^\n]*)` will find `key = value` pairs.

As a one-liner, assuming the contents of the file are in the variable `s`:

```
config= {key:dict(re.findall(r'([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*([^\n]*)', values)) for key,values in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*\{([^}]*)', s)}
```

Comment: Its so ugly my eyes bleed! I love it, have my upvote!

Comment: @Rawing Ah, yes !! It's awesomely ugly :). Could you pls help me understand it a bit. I cud get some of it like - \w, \s* \{ and [^}]. But not why + with \w and use of ( )

Comment: @mittal: The `+` makes it capture more than 1 character, without that it would only match the last character of the `key`. And the parentheses make it so that the matched text is captured and returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for less strict grammar:

```
from pyparsing import alphanums, restOfLine, OneOrMore, Word, Suppress
from copy import copy
lbrace,rbrace,eq = map(Suppress,"{}=")

configitem = {}
configall = {}

wd = Word(alphanums+'_')
kw = wd + eq + restOfLine
kw.setParseAction(lambda x: configitem.__setitem__(x[0],x[1].strip()))
group = wd + lbrace + OneOrMore(kw) + rbrace
group.addParseAction(lambda x: configall.__setitem__(x[0],copy(configitem)))
group.addParseAction(lambda x: configitem.clear())

config = OneOrMore(group)


config_file_string = '''app_id1 
{
key1 = val
key2 = val

key3 = val
}


app_id2 {
key1 = val

key2 = val

}'''

config.parseString(config_file_string)
print(configall)
```